# How can I make my axes visible with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes, graph-visualization

I am using matplotlib.pyplot to plot some graphs and for some reasons I can't see the lines of the axes, although I can see the xticks and yticks. Important to note that I am using python notebook, and usually I try to visualize my graphs with the function (%matplotlib inline)

Here is an example figure that I get (without the axes):

[image: example figure]

Here is the code I used to produce this figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(7.5,6), sharey=False, sharex=False, edgecolor='k', frameon=True)
ax.plot(np.array(frequency_vec), before_LTP, 'b-o', label='Before');
ax.plot(np.array(frequency_vec), After_LTP, 'r-o', label='After');
plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','0'], fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.rcParams['axes.edgecolor']='k'
ax.patch.set_visible(False) 
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_frame_on(True)
ax.set_xlim(0, 110)
ax.set_ylim(1,(Number_of_pulses)+2)
ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=15)
plt.xticks([12.5,25,50,75,100], ['12.5','25','50','75','100']);
```

So again - How can I make my axes-lines to be visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some special setting in your `matplotlibrc` file such as edgecolor?

`import matplotlib as mpl
print mpl.rcParams['axes.edgecolor']`

If it's 'w' (white) set it to 'k' (black)

If it's not edgecolor, do you have frameon = False? Try something like this:

`fig, ax = subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,4],[4,5,6], 'r^-')
ax.set_frame_on(True)`

Comment: Hi unfortunately it still doesn't work. I tried to change the edgecolor to black, and to press framon=True...

Comment: I tried: fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(7.5,6), sharey=False, sharex=False, edgecolor='k', frameon=True), and also: plt.rcParams['axes.edgecolor']='k'
ax.patch.set_visible(False) 
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_frame_on(True)

Comment: You code doesn't have anything special. Is there anything in your matplotlibrc file: `import matplotlib
print matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`

Comment: it returns: c:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that and it worked

```
 plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
 plt.axes().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Well, just write 'True' instead of 'False'.

Comment: This answer could be improved by some explanation as to the core issue.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, `plt.axes()` returns only a tuple and you cannot call `get_xaxis()` on a tuple.